# Turn RSS into array, explode the 'description' and insert words into MySQL table one per row

Tags: php, mysql, rss, explode

I have only recently gotten into php and MySQL and I want to take an RSS feed, turn it into an array, take only the description part of the XML, explode it and insert it into a table on a MySQL base.

I feel like this should be possible, but is a little over my head right now. I tried using magpie as a parser, but if possible I want to do it in simpler php code.

The result I am looking for would take a description "This is a cat" and insert it into a table with two fields

ID    term 
 
1      This  
2      is   
3      a    
4      cat

I've been stumped on this for a couple days. Any help would be great.

Based on Matt's help here is what I have so far. The server seemed to have a problem with the "new MySQLi" tag so I tried to change it, but it is still not depositing anything into my table...

```
 

$host="*******";
$username="*********";
$password="********";
$database="**********";

mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

$parser = xml_parser_create('UTF-8');
$values = array();
xml_parse_into_struct($parser, file_get_contents('*********'), $values);

$query = "INSERT INTO words VALUES('',$word)";

foreach ($values as $entry) {
    if ($entry['tag'] === 'SUMMARY') {
        $words = preg_split('/\s+/', strtolower(preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z\s]+/', '', strip_tags($entry['value']))));
        foreach ($words as $word) {
            $query->bind_param('s', $word);
            $query->execute();
        }
    }
}

mysql_close();
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: What have you got so far? Can you post what you have tried? What part don't you understand and what do you want help with? I don't think that there are many people here who will write your entire code for you but we're happy to help if you have a more specific question.

Comment: Make sure you have error reporting on for your development. If you are not using mysqli you need to firstly capture and make sure it connects to correctly with $con_sql = mysql_connect($host,$username,$password) OR die (mysql_error()); then use mysql_query($query,$con_sql) instead of $query->execute() as the $query is not an object, just a string.  Then encapsulate the $word parameter accordingly and remove the line $query->bind_param('s', $word);

Comment: If it still doesn't work it try print_r($values) after the xml_parse_into_struct() and see if it outputs something on the page. Then check the outputted arrays structure and see if it is correctly formatted according to the foreach and named values. If all of this still does not works remove @ before @mysql_select_db and check for errors.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an RSS reader class such as http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2552-PHP-Retrieve-and-parse-RSS-feeds-extending-feed-reader.html

It is really simple to use:

```
include("./files_includes/RSSReader.inc.php"); 
$rss = new RSSReader("http://www.php.net/news.rss");
```

see the example at http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/10759.html

I do not really understand why you would like to explode all the word in the description, but with that class you could do it something like:

```
explode(' ',$rss->getItemDescription("rsstext",$i));
```

Be aware that the class is dependent on the FeedReader-class: http://www.phpclasses.org/package/1811-PHP-Parse-and-extract-information-from-RSS-2-0-feeds.html - so you need to download that too.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the RSS feed is valid XML, you can use PHP's [XML parser](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php) to do this..

Here's a simple example running against Stack Overflow's [Recent Questions feed..](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds)

```
<?php
$parser = xml_parser_create('UTF-8');
$values = array();
xml_parse_into_struct($parser, file_get_contents('feed.xml'), $values);

$db = new MySQLi('localhost', 'root');
$db->select_db('test');
$db->query('create table if not exists words (id int unsigned primary key auto_increment not null, word varchar(255) not null)');
$stmt = $db->prepare('insert into words (word) values(?)');

foreach ($values as $entry) {
    if ($entry['tag'] === 'SUMMARY') {
        $words = preg_split('/\s+/', strtolower(preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z\s]+/', '', strip_tags($entry['value']))));
        foreach ($words as $word) {
            $stmt->bind_param('s', $word);
            $stmt->execute();
        }
    }
}
```

Once you have that, you can run fun queries like:

```
select word, count(*) from words
group by word
order by count(*) desc
```

Which returns result sets like:

```
+------+----------+
| word | count(*) |
+------+----------+
| the  |      127 |
| i    |       90 |
| to   |       74 |
|      |       60 |
| a    |       59 |
| is   |       45 |
| in   |       44 |
| and  |       41 |
| it   |       38 |
| have |       31 |

etc ...
```

Comment: Thanks Matt, that's a lot like what I am trying to do. I revised the code a little bit because I was having trouble with MySQLi, but it is still not working . .

Answer (score 0):

You need to end up with a `VALUES` clause of the form `('word1'),('word2'), ...` Something like this should work:

```
$string="This is a cat";
$arr=explode(' ',$string);
array_walk($arr, function(&$v,$i){ $v="('$v')"; }); //php5.3 syntax only, use create_function() otherwise

$values=implode(','$arr);
$query="INSERT INTO mytable(term) VALUES $values";
```